# Storing multiple lists in a single vertex in Gremlin - Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

How do I design it while adding the vertex itself? I see that we have to use `.properties` for this. But how do I do it for multiple lists?

{

```
"id": "95fcfa87-1c03-436d-b3ca-340cea926ee9",
"label": "person",
"type": "vertex",
 "States": [{
            "DeviceCount": "12",
            "SC_ItemStatus": "2",
            "SC_ItemWarningStatus": "0",
            "SC_SysemStandardPercentage": "1"
            }
           ],
 "log": [{
        "user": "user@user.dk",
        "action": "update",
        "timestamp": "22-03-2017",
        "field": "firstName",
        "oldValue": "Marco"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
g.addV("Person").
    property(single,"States","States" , "DeviceCount","12","SC_ItemStatus","2","SC_ItemWarningStatus","0","SC_SysemStandardPercentage","1").
    property(single,"Log","Log", "user","user@user.dk","action": "update","timestamp","22-03-2017","field", "firstName","oldValue", "Marco" );
```